# Inserting html code with markdown to a div, using a twig function

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, markdown

I want to use Markdown to preview to the user how a form field on a twig file will be styled using javascript.

Basically what I'm trying to do, is :

```
// This function is used to show the Description Preview 
$( "#server_new_profile_description" ).on('input propertychange', function() {
    // This should make the $(this).val() formated in markdown
    var descrString = $(this).val();
    $("#descriptionPrev div").html("{{- "+descrString+"|markdown|raw -}}");
});
```

What I get:
`If the input is *ABC*`

`the output will be: {{*ABC*|markdown|raw}}.`

instead of *ABC*

Can anyone get me through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig is rendered server-side, which means it gets executed only once, when you request the page. So you will have to use javascript functions to achieve the markdown effects. This means you will need a markdown parser, for example: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Answer (score 0):

I created HTML that looks like this.

```
<div id="server_new_profile_description"> 
<input type="text">
</div>

<div id="descriptionPrev">
</div>
```

And I would achieve what you are looking to do like this.

```
$( "#server_new_profile_description input" ).change(function() {
    var descrString = $(this).val();
    $("#descriptionPrev").html("{{*"+descrString+"*|markdown|raw -}}");
});
```

It grabs the input element that is inside the div with the server_new_profile_description ID and won change it grabs the value assigning it to a variable. That variable is then placed inside of the DIV with the ID of descriptionPrev and concatenated with the two string parts

Comment: Have you tested this? It is not working at all. I get exactly the same result but with stars this time.